# How to match attributes in different tables

Tags: sql

Say there are 3 tables, one with employee names, another with their salaries, and another with their IDs. How would I match all three of them?

Comment: you join them based on common keys.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use object for each tables, but there should have one column which common for three tables.
ex.
select t1.col1,t2.col2,t3.col3 from tbl1 t1,tbl2 t2,tbl3 t3

where t1.col1=t2.col1 and t1.col1=t1.col3

or you can use join keyword